# Order of elements in Z/10Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone help me with the following question:

How do I find the elements of order 5 i the group

$\mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: the order of an element $x$ is the smallest number $n$ such that $x+x+x+\dots+x$ ($n$ times) is equals to $0$.

Comment: There are only $10$ numbers; just list them and find their orders. An element $x$ has order $n$ if $nx=0$ and $mx\ne0$ for all $1\le m<n$

Comment: Do you know what the order of an element is...? If you do, then it shouldn't be too hard, since there are only $10$ elements in this group.

Answer (score 3):

The order of an element is the least number of times you must apply it to itself in order to get the identity. Here, $\overline{5}+\overline{5} = \overline{10} = \overline{0}$, so the order of $\overline{5}$ is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The order of $\bar n=n \cdot\bar 1$ is $\dfrac{10}{\gcd(n,10)}$. Hence we must find all positive integers $n\le 10$ such that $\gcd(n,10)=2$. The complete list is
$$\{\bar2, \bar4, \bar6,\bar8 \}.$$

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly the result i was looking for.